IronPython Spotfire Read and create a new table from unique values
I am new to IronPython in Spotfire and I am running into an issue I hope I can get it solved.
This is what I plan to achieve

Read the datatable
Filter unique values in the column "WELL" of the data table
output a new table with just the unique values of the "WELL" column (Column name WELL)

When I display the result, it looks fine but no table is outputted. and when I run the cursor2 line , I get the error "TypeError: expected IDataColumn, got DataColumn" . Any idea on why it happens and how to output the new table to spotfire.
Here is the code
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Data')
import System
from System.Data import DataSet, DataTable
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import IndexSet, DataValueCursor

myDataTable = Document.Data.Tables["dca_pdp_summary"]
column_name = "WELL"
cursor = DataValueCursor.CreateFormatted(myDataTable.Columns[column_name])
rowCount = myDataTable.RowCount
rowsToInclude = IndexSet(rowCount, True)

# Identify Unique Values in the column
unique_values_set = set()
for row in myDataTable.GetDistinctRows(rowsToInclude, cursor):
    unique_values_set.add(cursor.CurrentValue)

# Create a dictionary with unique values
data_dict = {column_name: list(unique_values_set)}

# Convert dictionary to a DataTable
dataSet = DataSet()
dataTable = DataTable("test_select")
dataTable.Columns.Add("WELL", System.String)
dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable)

# Populate the new DataTable with unique values
for value in data_dict[column_name]:
    new_row = dataTable.NewRow()
    new_row["WELL"] = value
    dataTable.Rows.Add(new_row)

# Displaying the result
for row in dataTable.Rows:
    print(row[column_name])

cursor2 = DataValueCursor.CreateFormatted(dataTable.Columns["WELL"])

When I add
dataSource=DataTableDataSource(dataTable)

I get this error TypeError: expected DataTable, got DataTable
